# CSOM or JSOM or REST for new SPS developers

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, csom, jsom

I want to get in to SPS development space and currently I`m more of a person who uses OOTB and aware of SharePoint Administration side.

Therefore would like which is the Programming model that I should follow to perform SPS development work.

Looking for:
- Easier adapt
- In trend
- Tried and tested

Any guidance will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to be writing managed code (C# or VB) then you should use the Client Object Model (CSOM). It has better documentation, the API has more coverage, it requires less lines of code, and it has better tooling in Visual Studio.

If you are going to be writing JavaScript, my suggestion would be to start with the JavaScript version of the Client Object Model (JSOM) only because it has better documentation and will take you less time to learn. Once you get comfortable with JSOM, then I would start to look at the REST API.

Understanding how to program against REST APIs in general will be important as you expand beyond just SharePoint into programming against other service provided by Microsoft, particularly the Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Any specific video series that can help to understand CSOM. I know it sounds kiddy, but that where I `m in SharePoint Development space.

Comment: Yes, I have a course on the subject on Pluralsight. SharePoint 2013 Development: Client Object Model and REST API (https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/sharepoint-2013-client-object-model-rest/table-of-contents)

Comment: I also have a conference talk that covers some of the material from the course. You can download the slide deck and the demos from http://ow.ly/4mRlUc

Comment: thanks Rob, I just had a glance of the presentation.

Let me ask you, in order to achieve the following is CSOM knowledge needed or some other scripting language would do - 

- Query data from multiple columns part of multiple SPS 2013 Lists and show in one Webpart.
- Total count of items in a SPS list to be calculated and reference in another Webpart.

Comment: It could be done but it would require some pretty complex code to do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can also check basic guide for CSOM using .net managed code from the following URL. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/ebooks/sharepoint-2013-dot-net-client-side-object-model-cookbook.

Thanks,
Alok